# Using Kendo UI MOBILE (Q3 2014 Beta) with AngularJS AND ui-router

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-ui-router

**Is it possible to combine Kendo UI Mobile and Angular UI Router?**

Currently I am using the Q3 2014 Beta of Kendo UI. But I still can not find a solution. Having a state with an url /welcome I get something like

```
GET http://localhost:4000/welcome?html 404 (Not Found)
```

If I remove the kendo view I get the message

> "Your kendo mobile application element does not contain any direct
>   child elements with data-role="view" attribute set. Make sure that you
>   instantiate the mobile application using the correct container."

Without Kendo UI the navigation is working fine. Is it possible to combine these two? Is it perhaps not recommended? Do I have to skip Kendo application if I want to use another routing? If the only chance is to use Kendo UI and plain AngularJS without routing (or is the default routing of angular possible?)... - how can I separate the view from the controller? All the kendo ui angular samples only show bad coding style...

Is it possible to combine Kendo UI Mobile and Angular UI Router? In other words:

```
<div kendo-mobile-application>
    <div ui-view>
</div>
```